# How can i use the values in my array to make it as a key word to select it

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli

Hi i have this idea of using the array values that i get in my database as a key to select one of them, I don't know how to get it but i had this code:

```
<?php

include('connect.php');
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
$query = "SELECT * FROM  sms_in WHERE  sent_dt = '2015-01-15'";
$data = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
  {
    $arr[] = $row['sms_text'];
  }

$arr= implode(' ' , $arr);

$Numeric = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $arr);
$arr = explode(' ', $Numeric);

print_r($arr);


?>
```

it gave me an array like this

> Array ( [0] => ACI [ 1 ] => TEM [2] => SAL [3] => OXY )

and I'm stuck on that

what I want to get is the number only.

for example If i select ACI it will give me the value 1 from its former value 1ACI

this is the former array

> Array ( [0] => 1ACI [1] => 2TEM [2] => 3SAL [3] => 4OXY )

Is my idea possible??
I hope I've been clear enough ... if not please let me know and I'll elaborate. Thanx in advance for your replies!

Comment: If I a getting correct from the value you need index of the next item or something. Why don't you try to use Linked List or Doubly Linked list. Linked lists looks me best in this case.

Comment: I'm new at this sir can you walk me through, Can linked list get the value 1 from 1ACI??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to do something like this:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        '1ACI',
        '2TEM',
        '3SAL',
        '4OXY',
    );

    $new_arr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        $key = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $val);
        $new_arr[$key] = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '', $val);
    }

    print_r($new_arr);
?>
```

That code will have following output:

```
Array ( [ACI] => 1 [TEM] => 2 [SAL] => 3 [OXY] => 4 )
```

So you can select desired item using square bracket, for example `$new_arr['ACI']` will return `1`.

Comment: thaks sir this helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to get your wished array with a loop:

```
$arr = array('ACI', 'TEM', 'SAL', 'OXY');

foreach($arr as $key => &$value) {
    $key++;
    $value = $key.$value;
}


print_r($arr);
```

Array ( [0] => 1ACI [1] => 2TEM [2] => 3SAL [3] => 4OXY )

Comment: this will output the array he get from his DB.